# On the products of lengths of adjacent sides in a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

I'm trying to fill in the details of a proof for which I only have a figure, as shown below:
[image]

...and a claim that refers to this figure<sup>1</sup>:

$$
\overline{EG} : \overline{GF} = ΔEDC : ΔFCD = \overline{ED}·\overline{EC} : \overline{FC}·\overline{FD}
$$

I cannot justify the second equality above.

Also, I would like to know if the claim is true for *any* cyclic quadrilateral $ECFD$ such that the angles at the opposing vertices $C$ and $D$ are right angles (as opposed to requiring some of the other details given in the figure).

---

Here's some additional information that may be useful.  First, the segment $AB$ is the diameter of the semicircle that also passes over $D$ and $C$.  Next, it is not difficult to show that triangles ACE and BDE are similar right triangles.  From this, together with the remaining lengths shown in the figure, one can deduce that (a) $\overline{EC} = 4$, and, therefore, (b) the acute angles of these similar right triangles are $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$.  (I don't know, however, how any of this relates to the claim above, if at all.)

---

<sup>1</sup> The notations $ΔEDC$ and $ΔFCD$ stand for the areas of the triangles $EDC$ and $FCD$, respectively.

Comment: Since you mention right triangles, you're assuming $\overline{AB}$ is a diameter of a semi-circle, correct? What other details about the figure we should know? For instance, is $|BD|=5$?

Comment: @Blue: Yes, $AB$ is the diameter of the semi-circle above it.  Thank you for pointing out the omission.  I just fixed it.  Regarding your other question, I have no additional information beyond what is already stated, but I think one can show that the length $\overline{BD}$ is actually $\sqrt{27}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot justify the second equality above.

Using the trigonometric formula for area of $ABC$ that $\Delta ABC=\frac{1}{2}bc\sin A$
$$\frac{\Delta EDC}{\Delta FDC}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}ED\cdot EC\sin E}{\frac{1}{2}FD\cdot FC\sin F}=\frac{ED\cdot EC}{FD\cdot FC}\quad \Leftrightarrow \sin E=\sin F$$
This means either $\angle E=\angle F$ or $\angle E+\angle F=180^\circ$ as in a cyclic quadrilateral. Clearly the claim about ratios will hold for any cyclic quadrilateral.